# How to start deskclock timer via NFC

Tags: automation, nfc

I am trying to start the timer of the deskclock app that comes with Android 4.2 using a NFC chip. I am not trying to write an app that does this but rather use one of the many NFC launcher apps.

I can't seem to find if that is possible at all... [AnyTAG NFC launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anytag.android) for example is able to launch the deskclock app but not set any parameters or just launch the timer part.

Answer (score 1):

[Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&hl=en) will let you launch a custom `INTENT` when it receives an NFC signal. I have not used this part of Llama, as I don't have NFC on my phone, but I have used it to create a custom `INTENT`.

This raises the question of whether you can set a specific timer and start it with an intent. I don't know if this is possible with the built-in app; you'd have to do your own research on that end.

But you could use Llama instead for the timer as well (if you can live with only whole minutes for the timer). Add a delay to the event, so that it will do something after X minutes of receiving the NFC scan. You can have the phone play a song, vibrate, launch another app, or basically anything supported.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Tasker and probably others can do the same thing (as long as they support NFC). I mention Llama because it is free and the only one I extensively use.

Answer (score 0):

[NFC Task Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher) can do exactly what you want, I think. It can set alarms, change volume and notification sound.

Comment: The problem with NFC Task Launcher is that it can't launch actions from random NFC tag IDs. I dont want to save the action on the tag but rather have the app remember tags, no matter what's written on them.

Comment: OK, that's true, I think. This requirement was not clear to me from your question, though. What is there against writing on a dedicated tag?

Comment: I want to use my company's access card to launch tasks :-D

Comment: And also, it seems Task Launcher will only set an alarm and not use the builtin timer. This is not what the alarm clock was meant to do and messes up my list of alarm clock times...

Comment: Makes sense. Perhaps it is worth it to submit a feature request to the developers. The app is regularly updated, so it is under active development.